# How to simulate postgresql sequence nextval in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, singleton, python-multithreading

I'd like to know what is the best way to simulate postgresql nexval in python 3.

I'd like to have variable / object attr whose value is autoincremented on request for its value. The same how db sequence nextval works. It will be "daily sequencer" whose value increments on each get call (and gonna reset on midnight using cronjob).

My idea was to use Singleton (with some persistent cache in back), but it fails in multithreaded environment.

```
class OnlyOne:
    class __OnlyOne:
        key = "key"

        def __init__(self):
            val = cache.get(self.key, None)
            if val is None:
                val = 0
                cache.set(self.key, val)
            self.val = val

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.nextval)

        @property
        def nextval(self):
            self.val += 1
            cache.set(self.key, self.val)
            return self.val

    instance = None

    def __init__(self):
        if not OnlyOne.instance:
            OnlyOne.instance = OnlyOne.__OnlyOne()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.instance, name)
```

Has somebody any better idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Python has a library called `threading` for that.

```
import threading
```

I think the simplest solution is just to put a lock around your property. You can think of how to better implement, but you could create a `Lock` in your `__init__`:

```
self.lock = threading.Lock()
```

And then wrap access of your attribute with locking:

```
self.lock.acquire() # grab the lock
# Code in here is single threaded
self.val += 1
retval = self.val
cache.set(self.key, self.val)
self.lock.release() # release the lock

return retval # Returning this to avoid a race with self.val
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Unfortunatelly I was not able to make it multiprocess safe. Final solution for me is to create async task for celery queue with one worker, so its a little bottleneck, but it's fast and not so painful.